# Objective C - How to write a macro

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, multiline

I need to write a multi-line macro. I need this because I must have partial code that has been "paste" into specific points in my code. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not really clear from your question what you actually want, but a plain multi-line macro is defined as follows:

```
#define FOO something; \
            something_else;
```

Of course, beware of the `if .. else` problem. If this is applicable to your case, you could wrap things into a `do { ... } while(0)` construct. This will ensure that it's treated as a single statement.

```
#define FOO do                 \
            {                  \
               something;      \
               something_else; \
            } while (0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the backslash character like in C.

```
#define NINE (3 \
  + 3)
```

Comment: hehe, defining NINE as the value 6! :D

Answer (score 0):

as in ansi c: http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/Macro-Preprocessor/Definingamacrotocomparetwovalues.htm